# transfering data between 2 python programs on different devices

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-18.04

I'm working on a project to control a drone using an EEG headset. The EEG headset is connected to my laptop [runnig ubuntu 18.04] and the drone to the raspberry pi [raspbian].

The code for processing the EEG data on the laptop as well as the code to control the drone is written on python 3.6 and work without any problems.

setup:

the EEG headset[ neurosky mindwave mobile 2] and the drone[ parrot mambo] both use BLE[bluetooth low energy] to connect with the devices. since both of them use Bluetooth it would be hard to send and receive data simultaneously to both the devices using a single code and laptop as they require a continuous uninterrupted connection and high data rates. hence the EEG headset is connected to the laptop via BLE and similarly the drone to the raspberry pi 3b+. The laptop takes care of processing the EEG signal and determining the desired command, while the raspberry pi acts as a wireless controller for the drone.
[system setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiuQL.jpg)

I need to pass the values between these 2 codes[and devices] so as to control the drone using the EEG signal. For eg, if I want to make the drone go forward after processing the signal I need to send say "1" or "f" to the raspberry pi from the laptop.

A  wired connection such as Ethernet cable or USB is preferred over a wireless method.

The data size and rate is very less as a single character is sufficient and it will be sent only once every few seconds.

Which would be the best method to achieve this sort of communication

Comment: I don't understand your equipment setup. You have a drone with a Raspberry Pi in it flying around and you want an Ethernet cable to your Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: Maybe you'd care to divulge which EEG headset you are using too? And check your post... "usually" is a funny sentence.

Comment: sorry, should have mentioned the setup. I have edited my question and added the details.

Comment: I'm even more confused now :-( What are *"the devices"* you talk about? Maybe you could add a diagram? What is joined to what by a cable?

Comment: I have added the image, I need to communicate between 2 and 3. I need to pass a value from the code in the laptop to the code running on the raspberry pi. it does not necessarily have to happen via a cable but it is preferred. thanks for your time! :)

Comment: I would go with serial communication over an Adafruit 954 or FTDI cable. Simple, reliable. Use PySerial module for access.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

Use [kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) or [0mq](http://zeromq.org/) to loosely couple the laptop sender to the rasp pi receiver.
If one of them reboots, that's ok, the other will keep plugging away.
In the kafka case, you will enjoy the advantage of being able to replay a laptop publisher session again and again as you tweak and test the rasp pi client code.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it.